Determine the continuity of a function
The following question appeared in a graduate-level entrance exam. In this question more than 1 option can be correct.

I determined that option A is incorrect since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are unbounded on $\mathbb R$.
For option B I think of a possible step function that could lie between these two polynomials or perhaps define $f(x)$ as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      p(x) & x\in \mathbb Q \\
     q(x) & x\notin \mathbb Q 
   \end{cases}
$$
with $q(x) \gt p(x) \,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb R$. I don't know if this is correct. This one also ends up disproving option D.
Option C also doesn't look possible because $p(x), q(x)>0$ $\forall x$.
I am missing out on something here. I would highly appreciate a detailed explanation.

But we must have $q(x) \geqslant p(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, but $q(x) - p(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $n - 1$ which is odd and leading coefficient $b_{n-1} - a_{n-1}$ which is positive, hence it tends to $-\infty$ when $x \to -\infty$ and this forms contradiction

Your explanation is correct but answer-key has marked option D as correct, looks like an incorrect question.

For $x<0$, since $n$ is even and $a_{n-1} < b_{n-1}$ we would have $a_{n-1} x^{n-1} > b_{n-1} x^{n-1}$. Thus $p(x) > q(x)$ for sufficiently large negative $n$.  The conclusion is that the function $f$ does not exist.
I suppose you could say "we can conclude" all of (A), (B), (C) and (D), since "X implies Y" is true when X is false.

So all the options are incorrect?

The answer key suggests that option D is correct.

If we restrict domain to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, then option D is correct.

@Mihail No, if we restrict the domain to $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, option D is wrong.  Try $p(x) = x^4 $ and $q(x) = x^4 + x^3 + 1$.  Option D would be correct if the statement were that $f(x)$ is always between $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, i.e. for every $x \in \mathbb R$,  $p(x) \le f(x) \le q(x)$ or $q(x) \le f(x) \le p(x)$.

@RobertIsrael The question does say $p(x) \le f(x) \le q(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$

@Mihail Can you explain why that would be the case?

This "answer" is answering the question asked by @Ark in the comments above. That is, if we have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ either $p(x) \leq f(x) \leq q(x)$ or $q(x) \leq f(x) \leq p(x)$ then $f(x)$ is continuous at at least one point.
$q(x)-p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Since $n-1$ is odd, this polynomial has at least one real root. Let $x_0$ be such a root and let $y_0=p(x_0)=q(x_0)=f(x_0)$. For any $\epsilon>0$ we can pick a $\delta_0>0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_0$ we have $|p(x)-y_0|<\epsilon/2$ and $|q(x)-y_0|<\epsilon/2$. Since $q-p$ is also continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can pick a $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ we have $|q(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$. Letting $\delta = \min\{\delta_0, \delta_1\}$, we have for all $x$, such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have
\begin{align}
|f(x)-y_0| 
&   = \frac{1}{2}\bigg( |y_0-f(x)| + |f(x)-y_0| \bigg) \\
&   = \frac{1}{2}\bigg( |y_0-q(x)+q(x)-f(x)| + |f(x)-p(x)+p(x)-y_0| \bigg) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\bigg( |y_0-q(x)|+|q(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-p(x)|+|p(x)-y_0| \bigg)\\
&=    \frac{1}{2}\bigg( |y_0-q(x)| + |q(x)-p(x)| + |p(x)-y_0| \bigg) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\\
&= \epsilon
\end{align}
Thus proving that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. The key is that $|q(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-p(x)| = |q(x)-p(x)|$ if and only if either $p(x) \leq f(x) \leq q(x)$ or $q(x) \leq f(x) \leq p(x)$.
